# How to determine the time complexity of an algorithm depending on a delta value

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pagerank

I have to study PageRank right now, and I have written this algorithm :

[image: Algorithm]

I have determined the complexity of the inside of the while loop, which I believe to be `O(n^2)`. But then I'm stuck with the complexity of the while loop itself, which is inherently determined by delta. Delta being the difference of the L1 norm of R at the iteration `i` and R at the iteration `i+1`.

Is there any method for determining such a complexity ?

EDIT : a bit more explanation :

- R is the rank vector
- epsilon is a value given by the user (we want epsilon to be small to have a good estimate of PageRank but not too small it takes ages to compute it)
- `creerMatricePageRank()` cretes the adjacency matrix for us, complete with the rank source vector `E` added in the mix
- A is the adjacency matrix

Answer (score 0):

The innermost `for` goes from 0 to `t`, which means `O(t)`. The outer `for` goes from 0 to `t`, which means `O(t) * O(t) = O(t^2)`.

Then you have another `for` which does nothing in `O(t)` time. It does nothing because it first computes `d2` and the statement right after it assigns the value of `d1` to `d2` (both are equal delta now). The next statement `delta = |d1 - d2|` is saying `delta = |delta - delta|` == `delta = 0`.

If epsilon is negative, then the `while` loop never ends, otherwise the loop ends after one iteration, which means `O(t^2)` complexity.

Something is obviously wrong with your code. You either don't need that `while` loop at all or you mixed up the assignments.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I mixed up the place of the line 20. it should be before the loop computing `d2`. But even then, is there a method for determining the algorithm's complexity when it depends on a delta value ?